# Removing interface elements from an xib file

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, xib

I have added some items, such as the pictured "round rect button" in Interface Builder to my .xib file, but I am not able to remove them.

[image: Highlighted round rect button in Interface Builder]

If I just click on the 'x', it disappears, but it's not removed from the interface. How do I actually delete it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Highlight the items as shown below and hit the delete key

[image]

If you can't see the menu it can be expanded by clicking the arrow in this image

[image]