# How to remove objects from Interface Builder in Xcode 5?

Tags: interface-builder, xcode5

How to remove an object which is added to Interface Builder from Object Library? I've removed it by simply dragging the object out over the place outside of Xcode and then letting go of it by dropping there. However, when I deleted it in such a way and run the simulator, Xcode crashes too often - so maybe, it's not an ideal way I think.

Also, I can't delete it in the same way as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9659017/removing-interface-elements-from-an-xib-file). Why? Or does Xcode 5 no longer support it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Select the object and the press the delete key. 
You could also then click on the edit menu and choose delete.

Comment: Ah, OK. Selecting the object itself, not the one in the view controller scene, did work! I didn't think it can be done so easily... Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can delete it by selecting that object under the View in document outline and hitting delete button. Document outline which is on the left of the editor screen. It is hidden, so you can view it by clicking on the small black box under the editor.